# TCPLister Pickel

Tags: c#, tcplistener

So my good ole boss came with me a question since I know my way around C# (not great but somewhat) and asked if it was possible to build a simple Syslog server rather than going out and buying one.  So of course I took the challenge on and went to town.  I have developed a Alpha one(which had the application input everything directly into the database) but he asked me if we could do a client vs listener approach(PIA but reasonable).  Now i believe I have the TCPClient constructed correctly but am stuck on the TCPlistener portion and would like some help if someone could point me in the right direction.  Below is 3 of the programs I have written thus far (the alpha, the client, adn a portion of the listener)

Alpha:

```
   EventLog alog = new EventLog();
   alog.Log = "Application";
   alog.MachineName = ".";
   DateTime fifteenMinsAgo = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-15);
   foreach (EventLogEntry entry in alog.Entries)
   {
   if (entry.TimeGenerated > fifteenMinsAgo)
   {
   SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection("Server=x.x.x.x;Database=yy;User ID=abcd;password=efg");
   sql.Open();
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"insert into ApplicationLog(Level,DateTime,Source,EventID,TaskCategory,ServerName,Message) values (@Level,@DateTime,@Source,@EventID,@TaskCategory,@ServerName,@Message)", sql);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Level", entry.EntryType);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime", entry.TimeGenerated);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Source", entry.Source);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventID", entry.InstanceId);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TaskCategory", entry.Category);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ServerName", entry.MachineName);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Message", entry.Message);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   sql.Close();

            }
        }
```

TCPClient:

```
   EventLog alog = new EventLog();
   alog.Log = "Application";
   alog.MachineName = ".";
   DateTime fifteenMinsAgo = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-15);
   foreach (EventLogEntry entry in alog.Entries)
   {
   if (entry.TimeGenerated > fifteenMinsAgo)
   {
     TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
     IPEndPoint serverendpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("x.x.x.x"), yyyy);
     client.Connect(serverendpoint);
     NetworkStream clientstream = client.GetStream();
     ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
     byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes(entry.ToString());
     clientstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
     clientstream.Flush();
            }
        }
```

TCPListener:

```
    TcpListener tcpServerListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), yyyy);
    tcpServerListener.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Server Started");
    Socket serverSocket = tcpServerListener.AcceptSocket();
    if (serverSocket.Connected)
    {
      NetworkStream serverSockStream = new NetworkStream(serverSocket);
      serverSockStream.ReadByte();
    }
```

Comment: Where are you setting the port number in your listener?

Comment: In the First line in the TCPListener where it states yyyy.  Sorry I should have clarified that.